# Mysql select 4 tables with 3 count

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have four tables

```
users
ID  display_name
1   Name1
2   Name2
3   Name3
```

A user can add books to table books

```
books
book_id AddedByuserID
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       3
```

Also a user can add ebooks to table ebooks

```
ebooks
ebook_id AddedByuserID
1       1
2       2
3       2
4       3
```

Now a user can add books only to his collection (not ebooks)

```
collection
userID  book_id
1       1
1       2
1       3
```

I need an output like this:

```
display_name    books_added ebooks_added    books_in_collection
Name1           2           1               3
Name2           1           2               2
Name3           1           1               1
```

This is what got:

```
SELECT users.*, COUNT(DISTINCT collection.book_id) AS books_in_collection, COUNT(DISTINCT books.AddedByuserID) AS books_added, COUNT(DISTINCT ebooks.AddedByuserID) AS ebooks_added
FROM users LEFT JOIN collection ON users.ID = collection.userID
LEFT JOIN books ON users.ID = books.AddedByuserID
LEFT JOIN ebooks ON users.ID = ebooks.AddedByuserID
GROUP BY users.ID
ORDER BY display_name ASC
```

The user display_name gets displayed correct and also the collection count, but the two other counts are showing 1.
If I remove DISTINCT the collection count says 86, and the two other counts show nothing.

I try to understand LEFT join and read tutorials but i'm stuck at the moment.

Comment: And what happened to `Name3`?

Comment: I updated the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest correlated subqueries:

```
select u.*,
       (select count(*) from collection c where u.id = c.userId) as books_in_collection,
       (select count(*) from books b where u.id = b.AddedByUserId) as books_added,
       (select count(*) from ebooks e where u.id = e.AddedByUserId) as ebooks_added
from users u;
```

I don't know why you are filtering out the third user, however.

Comment: I forgot to output the third user. i will try your code now.

Comment: Thanks your code is working fine! Is there any way I can SORT BY books_in_collection?

Comment: Yes,  for this kind of result it is always better to use subqueries.

Comment: Right it is working with ORDER BY books_in_collection. Thank you saved my day :)